# IOS - Recursive Functions leaves Memory Allocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I have a Test App, what i have in this App is a call made via a PHP script, once the data comes back the Recursive call is made again and again PHP Script is called and so on:

Whats happening is that every time [Self recusiveForumActivity]; is called i get 300kb of memory allocated and the memory usage keeps climbing when this recursive method is called. If i remove the method the memory usage stays stable. How can i overcome this so that i don't loose memory allocation at all, when the recursive method is called every time?

This is the code:

```
//
        //  ViewController.m
        //  Test
        //
        //  Created by trikam patel on 30/06/2015.
        //  Copyright (c) 2015 trikam patel. All rights reserved.
        //

        #import "ViewController.h"

        @interface ViewController ()

        @end

        @implementation ViewController


        -(NSString*)setupPhpCall:(NSString*)requestString :(NSString*)sciptPage{

            //NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:0];
            //[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];


            NSHTTPURLResponse *urlresponse = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *response = @"";
            NSData *myRequestData = nil;
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
            NSData *returnData = nil;

            myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

            //Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
            request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.hugt.co.uk/%@", sciptPage]]];
            // set Request Type
            [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
            // Set content-type
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
            // Set Request Body
            [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
            // Now send a request and get Response
            //NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
            //NSError *error = nil;

            //if(tmpArray.count == 0){
            returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error: &error];
            response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //}
            // Log Response
            urlresponse = nil;
            error = nil;
            myRequestData = nil;
            request = nil;
            returnData = nil;

            //NSLog(@"%@",response);/****/
            //[sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
            if(response != nil){

            return response;
            }

            return nil;
        }

        -(void)recurseForumActivity{
            dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


            __block NSString *myRequestStringForum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastDate=%@&threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@&getData=0",@"",@"", @"", @"", @""];
            __block NSString *responseForum = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestStringForum :@"getThreadRecurse.php"];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

                dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
                    responseForum = @"";
                    myRequestStringForum = @"";
                    [self recurseForumActivity];
                });
                });

            });

            });

        }

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            [self recurseForumActivity];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `[object performSelector:method]` instead of recursive call. A recursive function must always have a base/exit condition and your code doesn't have any such condition. So you must not make any recursive call here.

```
- (void)recurseForumActivity{
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

        __block NSString *myRequestStringForum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastDate=%@&threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@&getData=0",@"",@"", @"", @"", @""];
        __block NSString *responseForum = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestStringForum :@"getThreadRecurse.php"];

        YourClass * __weak weakSelf = self;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    responseForum = @"";
                    myRequestStringForum = @"";
                    [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(recurseForumActivity) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
                });
            });

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: still i get memory allocated of 300kb still what if i used recursive blocks?

Comment: even recursive blocks dont work as the memory is still being allocated to 300kb

Comment: @redoc01: Memory will get allocated anyhow because calling a function involves storing return address, address of the function being called etc. . The thing that you should check is that the memory footprint of your application doesn't keep on increasing.

Comment: can this be solved? because i have spent 3 days on this and im trying everything i can find.

Comment: @redoc01: You need not worry about 300kb being allocated. What you should worry about that 300kb getting deallocated as new 300kb gets allocated. Run your application and select 'debug navigator' tab on the left side of Xcode. You can check the memory footprint of your application there. Its should not keep on  increasing.

Comment: i have checked its what i have been checking for time and yes its always increasing by 300kb

Comment: It should not increase when you are using 'performSelector:' because 'performSelector' asynchronously dispatches a message to object, that will be executed later on the current runloop.  The "performSelector" call would return immediately, and the message to object will only be put on the current runloop after some time. Hence there is no cyclic call to the function.

Comment: It seems to be because i am running the same code you recommended, let me test some more

Comment: i have removed these lines   __block NSString *myRequestStringForum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastDate=%@&threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@&getData=0",@"",@"", @"", @"", @""];
        __block NSString *responseForum = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestStringForum :@"getThreadRecurse.php"];
 now the memory usage stays stable, i need these two lines of code though.

Comment: it must be these two lines of code where the memory usage is increasing?

Comment: @Rob, i have had some help off tek3, and he has solved the recursive memory usage that was happening and i think where the memory allocation is increasing is now due to the setupPhpCall

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82026/discussion-between-tek3-and-redoc01).